# WhatIf Google Tensorboard Tutorial confusion

Tags: docker, tensorflow, localhost, tensorboard

I am trying to use WhatIf to interpret a model and followed along this here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/interactive_inference#what-do-i-need-to-use-it

In particular I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/interactive_inference/WIT_from_scratch.ipynb

However parts of it are poorly written. I finally got my docker to spin up a localhost at port 8005 with this command: `docker run -p 8500:8500 --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/mod
els/iris",target=/models/iris -e MODEL_NAME=iris -t tensorflow
/serving` which output this: `I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:301] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
[evhttp_server.cc : 235] RAW: Entering the event loop ...`

I then in my Anaconda command line I ran `tensorboard --logdir .` as the tutorial told me to which outputted this: `TensorBoard 1.9.0 at http://DESKTOP-[serial_code_for_my_computer]:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

The tutorial tells me to "Navigate to http://localhost:6006/#whatif&inferenceAddress=localhost%3A8500&modelName=iris"

However nothing loads when I do this. I suspect there is some disconnect between my Docker which is hosting at localhost:8500 and my tensorboard which is at DESKTOP-[computer_serial]:6006? This last URL loads an empty tensorboard with nothing in it but even when I add #whatif&inferenceAddress=localhost%3A8500&modelName=iris to this DESKTOP URL it fails to load anything.

Thank you for any help that can be provided. I look forward to being able to use WhatIf!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the model name you enter to both of docker command and localhost address should've been matched. For me, the tensorboard loaded successfully the instances but not other functionalities, and made requestnetworkerror. Hope it helps.